# ORACLE find the first day and last day of a given quarter

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way I can find the first day and last day of a given quarter?

If I select first quarter then I should be able to get 
the first day and last day of the first quarter

example:

`quarter = 1` and year is `2016`. expected result is `01/01/2016` - `31/03/2007` (`DD/MM/YYYY` format).

for example:

```
select(quarterdatestart, quarterdatedate) where year = 2016 and quarter = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do with following:

First day of the current year:

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE , ‘YEAR’) FROM DUAL;
```

Last day of the current year:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC (SYSDATE, ’YEAR’), 12) - 1 FROM DUAL;
```

By the way, you can use the following to find the desired output:

```
with q(qtr) as( 
      select add_months( DATE '2016-01-01',
      (level - 1) * 3 ) from dual connect by level <= 4 )
       select qtr as first_day,
      last_day(add_months(qtr, 2)) as last_day 
from q
```

Comment: `dateadd` and `datediff` are SQL Server functions, not Oracle functions.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: unnecessarily complex, oracle supports the `Q` date format for quarters.

Answer (score 5):

```
trunc( sysdate, 'Q' )
```

will give you the first day of the current quarter.

```
trunc( add_months(date '0001-01-01', (y-1)*12 + (q-1)*3), 'Q' )
```

will give you the first day of quarter `q` in year `y`.  An example of calling this with different year and quarter values

```
with x as (
  select 2016 y, 1 q from dual union all
  select 2016, 2 from dual union all
  select 2015, 4 from dual
)
select trunc( add_months(date '0001-01-01', (y-1)*12 + (q-1)*3), 'Q' ) 
  from x
```

To get midnight on the last day of the quarter, simply add three months and subtract a day

```
<<first day of quarter>> + interval '3' month - interval '1' day
```

or

```
add_months(<<first day of quarter>>, 3) - 1
```

I generally find the interval syntax a bit more expressive but the older syntax is more compact.

If you want the last date in the quarter (23:59:59 on the last day of the quarter), simply subtract 1 second rather than 1 day.

Comment: I dont understand this `trunc( add_months(date '0001-01-01', (y-1)*12 + (q-1)*3, 'Q' )` is not working for me

Comment: @Giorgos - I missed a paren.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  ADD_MONTHS( to_date('01/01/2017','dd/mm/rrrr') ,3*(:quarter-1)) first, ADD_MONTHS( to_date('01/01/2017','dd/mm/rrrr') ,3*:quarter)-1 last   FROM dual
```

Comment: Plirkee if i have a date 2/2/2016 and quarter 3 how it works?

Comment: you mean that your quarter does not start at a first of the month? you haven't mentioned that in your question... however it will still work I guess. Do you find any particular problem with this solution?

Comment: Check the query that I've given.

Comment: @Giorgos results are  `2/8/2016`,`1/11/2016`  for  `2/2/2016` and quarter `3`

Comment: @Giorgos how did you get your results?